# CGAL Inexact Volume calculation

Tags: c++, c, cgal

### My Problem

I would like to calculate the exact volume for an intersection with polygonmeshes. Unfortunately the result is **wrong!?!?!**.
I think it has something to do with **me** choosing the wrong options.
I have an STEP/OFF file (both work). I move a smaller Cylinder into a bigger Cylinder.
Then I calculate the Intersection. I do not use a pointmap.
If I calculate the Volume of the first three intersections, CGAL tells me their volume is zero, but it is not.

### Why the Result is wrong

I know this, because:

1. I described this Problem analytically and solved the integral with matlab => Volume is not 0
2. I solved the Problem Using FreeCAD => Volume is the same as in Matlab
3. I solved the Volume in CGAL **Result do not match 1 and 2**.

I wrote the Results of many all the intersection into files, and the files concerning the problem are **not** empty. With a mesh viewer like (gmsh or meshlab) I can confirm heigth width and length. So the volume should not be 0, because it is intersecting so the volume cannot be 0.

### What I have done

I have read this:

1. [The Exact Computation Paradigm](https://www.cgal.org/exact.html)
2. [Robustness and Precision Issues in Geometric Computation](https://qgis.projets.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/attachments/download/100/Lectura_1.pdf)
3. [FAQ: I am using double (or float or ...) as my number type and get assertion failures or incorrect output. Is this a bug in CGAL?](https://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#inexact_NT)

I did not understand how these three apply to my situation.

I am using the `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel`, I defined `CGAL_DONT_USE_LAZY_KERNEL`. I have used the other Kernels and not defined `CGAL_DONT_USE_LAZY_KERNEL`, the result does not change.
I do not use the the same output and input variable for intersection like in the
[Polygon_mesh_processing/corefinement_consecutive_bool_op.cpp](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2corefinement_consecutive_bool_op_8cpp-example.html), so i do not use a point map as a result.

If needed I will supply the entire example, but I think, I did something wrong and the includes and way how I calculate the volume should suffice.

```cpp
// originalExampleFrom corefinement_parallel_union_meshes.cpp;
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel_with_sqrt.h>
//#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/transform.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/intersection.h>
#include <CGAL/Named_function_parameters.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/named_params_helper.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/aff_transformation_tags.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/triangulate_faces.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/corefinement.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/repair.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/IO/polygon_mesh_io.h>
#include <CGAL/Aff_transformation_3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // for write to file
#include <cassert>
#include <typeinfo>
//#define CGAL_DONT_USE_LAZY_KERNEL

/*
 The corefinement operation (which is also internally used in the three Boolean operations) will correctly change the topology of the input surface mesh
 if the point type used in the point property maps of the input meshes is from a CGAL Kernel with exact predicates.
 If that kernel does not have exact constructions, the embedding of the output surface mesh might have self-intersections.
 In case of consecutive operations, it is thus recommended to use a point property map with points from a kernel
 with exact predicates and exact constructions (such as CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel).
 In practice, this means that with exact predicates and inexact constructions, edges will be split at each intersection with a triangle but the position of the intersection point might create self-intersections due to the limited precision of floating point numbers.
 */
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel; //read text abouve about kernel
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3> Mesh;
#define CGAL_DONT_USE_LAZY_KERNEL
namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;

bool simulateDrillingRadial(Mesh cutter, Mesh rotor, Mesh &out, double step) { //Kernel::Point_3 *volume
    bool validIntersection = false;
    CGAL::Aff_transformation_3<Kernel> trans(CGAL::Translation(),
            Kernel::Vector_3(0, step, Z_INIT)); // step * 2
    PMP::transform(trans, cutter);
    assert(!CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::does_self_intersect(rotor));
    assert(!CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::does_self_intersect(cutter));
    assert(CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::does_bound_a_volume(cutter));
    assert(CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::does_bound_a_volume(rotor));
    validIntersection = CGAL::exact(
            PMP::corefine_and_compute_intersection(cutter, rotor, out));
#ifndef NDEBUG
    CGAL::IO::write_polygon_mesh("union" + std::to_string(step) + ".off", out,
            CGAL::parameters::stream_precision(17));
    assert(validIntersection);
    std::cout << "Cutter Volume: " << PMP::volume(cutter) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rotor  Volume: " << PMP::volume(rotor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Out    Volume: " << CGAL::exact(PMP::volume(out)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Numb. of Step: " << step << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bohrtiefe    : " << Y_INIT - DRMAX * 1.0 / ND * step
            << std::endl;
#endif
    return validIntersection;
}
```

The Rest of the CODE:

```
bool simulateDrillingRadial(Mesh cutter, Mesh rotor, Mesh &out, double step) { //Kernel::Point_3 *volume
    bool validIntersection = false;
    CGAL::Aff_transformation_3<Kernel> trans(CGAL::Translation(),
            Kernel::Vector_3(0, step, Z_INIT)); // step * 2
    PMP::transform(trans, cutter);
    assert(!CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::does_self_intersect(rotor));
    assert(!CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::does_self_intersect(cutter));
    assert(CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::does_bound_a_volume(cutter));
    assert(CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::does_bound_a_volume(rotor));
    validIntersection = CGAL::exact(
            PMP::corefine_and_compute_intersection(cutter, rotor, out));
#ifndef NDEBUG
    CGAL::IO::write_polygon_mesh("union" + std::to_string(step) + ".step", out,
            CGAL::parameters::stream_precision(17));
    assert(validIntersection);
    std::cout << "Cutter Volume: " << PMP::volume(cutter) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rotor  Volume: " << PMP::volume(rotor) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Out    Volume: " << CGAL::exact(PMP::volume(out)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bohrtiefe    : " << step << std::endl;
#endif

    return validIntersection;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    bool validRead = false;
    bool validIntersection = false;

    Mesh cutter, rotor; //out; // , out;
    Mesh out[ND];
    Kernel::Point_3 centers[ND];
    //Kernel::FT volume[ND];
    //GetGeomTraits<TriangleMesh, CGAL_NP_CLASS>::type::FT volume[ND];
    double steps[40] = { 40.0000, 39.9981, 39.9926, 39.9833, 39.9703, 39.9535,
            39.9330, 39.9086, 39.8804, 39.8482, 39.8121, 39.7719, 39.7276,
            39.6791, 39.6262, 39.5689, 39.5070, 39.4404, 39.3689, 39.2922,
            39.2103, 39.1227, 39.0293, 38.9297, 38.8235, 38.7102, 38.5893,
            38.4601, 38.3219, 38.1736, 38.0140, 37.8415, 37.6542, 37.4490,
            37.2221, 36.9671, 36.6740, 36.3232, 35.8661, 35.0000 };
    const std::string cutterFile = CGAL::data_file_path("Cutter.off");
    const std::string rotorFile = CGAL::data_file_path("Rotor.off");
    validRead = (!PMP::IO::read_polygon_mesh(cutterFile, cutter)
            || !PMP::IO::read_polygon_mesh(rotorFile, rotor));
    assert(!validRead);
    PMP::triangulate_faces(cutter);
    PMP::triangulate_faces(rotor);
    PMP::transform(rotAroundX(M_PI / 2), cutter);
    for (int i = 0; i < ND; i++) {
        //simulateDrillingRadial(Mesh & cutter, Mesh & rotor, Mesh & out, unsigned int step)
        simulateDrillingRadial(cutter, rotor, out[i], steps[i] + 10);
    }
    writeToCSV("tmp.csv", ND, out, steps);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the `CGAL::exact` to assign the result of the `PMP::corefine_and_compute_intersection` to boolean variable?

Comment: From What I can see. I already did that :(.
I added the rrelevant code.

Comment: If you provide something I can run with an assertion or a condition telling me that the result is incorrect, I can debug it otherwise it is hard to tell what can go wrong. AFAIS you are using EPECK so it should be fine as long as the output is manifold.

Comment: How would I send you the files. I am reading in `Cutter.off` and `Rotor.off`. My problem is not, that an assertion fails,  but that the results do not meet my expectations. I take a step off 0.0019mm.

I fear it could be connected to the mesh I import. 
Maybe I do not have a radius of 40 as designed in my CAD, but due to exporting it to a Mesh, my cylinder is approximated by py rectangles and the volume is actually really zero, since the side of the cylinder is really not round, but an n-gon.
I'm trying to confirm this right now.

Answer (score 0):

Change the output format of your mesh from `*.off` to `*.stl`, then open the intersection mesh in a software like Autodesk Netfabb which can detect and repair errors in the meshes being loaded. I think there’s a high chance the functions you’re using generate meshes with bugs. Possible bugs include holes, duplicate triangles, and self-intersections. Strictly speaking, such meshes do not unambiguously define a solid body and they have no volume.

If you confirm that’s the problem, there’re two ways to fix.

1. Replace or fix the intersection algorithm making it produce watertight meshes with no self-intersections or duplicate triangles. Maybe the [Nef Polyhedra](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_3/index.html#Chapter_3D_Boolean_Operations_on_Nef_Polyhedra) from the same library will help.
2. Replace volume computation algorithm making it tolerant to the bugs you have in your intersection meshes.

I realize the answer is rather vague. The reason for that — the problem is very hard to solve well. Very smart people published research papers over several decades. Some companies even selling commercial libraries just for reliable Boolean operations on 3D meshes.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.
My Problem with the NEF_Polehydra is, that I would like to use Cylinders, so I do not have Polyhydras. So to my understanding, this Library does not fit my needs!?

Comment: @blusser Convert your input shapes to triangular meshes or other polyhedra. You gonna loose some precision for splines such as cylinders, but that’s often OK because you can control that precision at the cost of more triangles in the mesh. Count of triangles affects performance of handling these meshes later on. Specifically, in CAD/CAM the reasonable precision is often about 1 micrometer, for 3D graphics people are often fine with larger 0.1 mm errors.

Comment: I have imported the created Mesh into FreeCAD and into Autodesk Fusion 360. I did not get an error message, like descirbed in (the tutorial baout broken meshes)[https://help.autodesk.com/view/fusion360/ENU/courses/AP-MESH-REPAIR]. I therefore assume my meshes are not broken. I have imported as Nef Polyhedra. Although I did not calculate the Volume, the NEF Polyhydra would not calculate the intersection for my smallest step. My Step is 0.0019mm (My transform Vector has a 49.9981, the original Position is 50).

Comment: I used similar Kernels, so I think it is Kernel dependent. (*Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel*)

Comment: The function used does not generate any topological issues in meshes. You can have some geometric issues (self-intersections) when using a kernel with inexact constructions is used when rounding from exact to floating point. Side note: it you have a mesh with issues, to do not convert it to STL as you are lossing topological information that could make it the mesh even harder to fix.